# Receiving ping pong on closed connection

Tags: node.js, nginx, websocket

I am using nodejs and ws to create a websocket server. The server runs behind a nginx proxy. 
I have written a c client using libwebsocket which connects to this client. This setup works well for couple of days but after that connection is reported closed  on nodejs server but client still continues to receive pong for each ping it sends.

Nginx config is as followes

`proxy-connect-timeout:120
proxy-read-timeout:3600
proxy_send_timeout:3600`

in libwebsocket

`ka_time :  10s;
  ka_probes: 3;
  ka_interval: 120s;
ws_ping_pong_interval: 120s`

Question 1) Does nginx send response to ping sent by client? 
Question 2) What can be the config to avoid this?

Comment: it should not receive ping-pong if the the connection is closed, websockets connection are upgraded from http request to TCP connections I don't see how Nginx blocks or stalls connections. Check if the RFC that is being used is latest, create an test client with ws, use examples and see if host happens again. If the client with libwebsocket might be reconnecting after connection loss. You need to debug your application , produce more output .